Convolution over set of monic polynomials with sublinear integer coefficients
Consider the set $\mathbb{F}_M[x]$ of monic polynomials over the real or complex numbers with positive integer coefficients such that for any $p\in \mathbb{F}_M[x]$ with $p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^k a_{k-j}x^j$ we have $0<a_j\leq j+1$. These polynomials arise as characteristic polynomials of a certain family of matrices.
I am looking for a convolution $\ast$ of polynomials, which preserves the property $0<b_j\leq j+1$ and $b_j$ integers if for $p,q\in \mathbb{F}_M[x]$ with $\mathrm{deg}(p)=k,\mathrm{deg}(q)=l$ and $(p\ast q)(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{k+l}b_{k+l-j}x^{j}$. The typical product of polynomials does not work, since for example $(x+1)(x^2+2x+2)=x^3 + 3x^2 + 4x + 2$, which fails to meet the condition, since for example $b_1=3>2=j+1$.
I tried also the symmetric additive convolution for $p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^k a_{k-j}x^j$ and $q(x)=\sum_{j=0}^k c_{k-j}x^j$ in the form
$$(p\ast q)(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{k+l}x^j\sum_{r+s=j}\dfrac{(k+l-r)!(k+l-s)!}{(k+l)!(k+l-j)!}a_rc_s.$$
using the same example as before $(x+1)(x^2+2x+2)$ we get that the term $r+s=2$ gives with $k+l=3$ and $j=2$ the result
$$\dfrac{2!2!}{3!1!}a_1c_1+a_0c_2 =\dfrac{4}{3}+1\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$$
such that the coefficients do not respect the integer condition.
In the end, the question boils down to finding a family of matrices $T^{n}=(t^{(n)}_{i,j})$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, independent of the coefficients of $p,q$ such that
$$(p\ast_T q)(x):=\sum_{j=0}^{k+l}x^j\sum_{r+s=j}a_rt^{(k+l)}_{r,s}c_s$$
has integer sublinear coefficients for any $p,q$.
But now, if I chose the examples $a=(1,2)$ and $b=(1,2,3)$, then $k+l=4$ and $6t_{2,3}\in\left\lbrace 1,2,3,4\right\rbrace$ which means that
$$t_{2,3}\in\left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{6},\dfrac{2}{6},\dfrac{3}{6},\dfrac{4}{6}\right\rbrace.$$ But with the example $a'=(1,1)$ and $b'=(1,1,1)$ the last coefficient of the convolution $(p\ast_T q)$ becomes $t_{2,3}$ which is, hence, necessarily a fraction.
Does this disprove the existence of a convolution of polynomials in the form $(p\ast_T q)$ which respects the sublinear integer coefficients? Or am I overseeing something?
